# how to send multiple selected checkbox checked value from nested loop with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

[image]

**In above image P means Parent and C means child and 1 attached to computer indicated computer is child of Electronics likewise MySql is child of Computer programming**.

I want to send multiple selected checkbox value with ajax to my controller and filter data based on selected checked value.

This is my model:

```
public class sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<childsample> childsamples { get; set; }
}

public class childsample
{
    public int childid { get; set; }
    public string child { get; set; }
}
```

My view(.cshhtml):

```
@foreach (var sample in Model.sample)
{
    <label class="Parentlabel">
        <input type="checkbox" name="parentHeader" class="ParentHeader Right5" />
        @sample.parent 
    </label>
    <div class="bgContainer">
        @foreach (var child in @sample.childsamples)
        {
            <label class="childLabel">
                <input class="ChildHeader Right5" type="checkbox" name="childHeader" value="@child.child" />@child.child
            </label>
        }
    </div>
}
```

My controller:

```
Public ActionResult filterData(int [] checkedIds) // if id is passed as paramter from ajax
```

Can anybody tell me how do i send this multiple checked checkbox value to
my controller with ajax and filter data based on checked checkbox value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can achieve this using java script array

To get a parent ID you should assign a value for parent checkbox likewise in child checkbox

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="parentHeader" class="ParentHeader Right5" value="@sample.Id" /> @sample.parent
```

**Ajax call**

Call the ajax function in both parent and child class

```
    $(".ParentHeader, .ChildHeader").click(function () {
        var parentValueToPush = new Array();
        var childValueToPush = new Array();

        // Parent checked check box value
        $('.ParentHeader:checked').each(function () {
            parentValueToPush.push($(this).val());
        });

        // Child checked check box value
        $('.ChildHeader:checked').each(function () {
            childValueToPush.push($(this).val());
        });

        var obj = {
            ParentCheckedIds: parentValueToPush,
            ChildCheckedIds: childValueToPush,
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/filterData',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
    public void filterData(List<int> ParentCheckedIds, List<int> ChildCheckedIds) 
    {
     // Code
    }
```

Comment: you can see in the image that my list consist of both parent and child and on each and every selection of checkbox i want to call my controller method.so my question is i need to handle individual event for both parent and child checkbox check event?

Comment: Are you want to send all the checked check box ID to controller every time user checked/unchecked the check box(both parent and child)?

Comment: yes i want to send all the checked checkbox id to controller every time user checked/unchecked the checkbox of both parent and child and most importantly how to unhandle the check and uncheck event of both parent and child that is what i am not getting

Comment: I have edited the answer, now the controller will receive both parent and child IDs during the click event of parent and child check box